# Displaying chosen carousel slide in another div

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I'm making portfolio for myself and i have chosen to display projects in a carousel.
I want it to display bigger picture, title and description of the chosen(clicked) project in another div that is below the carousel.
I have made a projects array which contains:

```
let projects = [
    {
        title: "ToDoApp",
        image: ('./images/projects/ToDoApp.jpg'),
        thumbnail: ('./images/projects/ToDoApp_tn.jpg'),
        github: "https://github.com/HereWasMynamelol/To-do-app",
        description: "My to-do application using HTML, CSS and JS. I have made this application so you can dynamically add " +
        "and delete your daily to-do's. All tasks are stored in a local storage and removed from it when finished. " +
        "I have not add a remove function to the check button to prevent accidental deletion of a task. "
    },
    {
        title: "agsdp",
        image: ('./images/project.jpg'),
        thumbnail: ('./images/project.jpg'),
        github: "https://github.com/HereWasMynamelol/To-do-app",
        description: "eh"
    },
]
```

And thanks to :

```
projects.forEach(project => {
    track.innerHTML += `
        <li class="carousel__slide">                                
            <img src=${project.thumbnail} alt="" class="carousel__images">
        </li>`
})
```

It's adding thumbnails to the carousel as i wanted. Now i want to click on it and display it's title, image and description in div :

```
                <div class="carousel__display">
                    <h1 class="carousel__display--title"></h1>
                    <div class="carousel__display--content">
                        <div class="carousel__display--image"></div>
                        <div class="carousel__display--description">
                        <p class="carousel__display--description-paragraph"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How should i go about it ? I already have click event listener attached to every slide for moving around the carousel and tried to add to it:

```
            projects.forEach((project) => {
                display__img.innerHTML = `${project.image}`
                display__desc.innerHTML = `${project.description}`;
            })
```

But i think it will try to add descriptions for every project with just a single click and i will end up with a mess or just the description of the last item in the projects array.
Sorry for such a long question but i have no idea how to explain it better. Tried googling it, no luck

Comment: I think you're on the right track! Each slide needs an event listener to handle a click event. Then you could use data stored on the event itself to add content to another div. I'm not seeing any click events in the code you provided, but if that projects.forEach() function is running every click, then you've got a problem. Instead of a forEach, look at your event to determine which slide was clicked.

Comment: Yeah projects.forEach is inside the click event listener so it runs on every click. I have tried projects.e.target but i don't think i have put it together well enough so it wasn't really working ? Any idea how should i change that ? TIA

Comment: Replace the forEach with 'console.log(e)' If 'e' is undefined make sure it's passed to the event handler as an argument. function clickHandler(e){console.log(e)}. Look for e.target and you should be able to tell which element was clicked.

Comment: So i finally managed to finish displaying function and it works with .forEach() :) Looks like this:
```projects.forEach(project => {
    if(e.target.classList == `carousel__images ${project.title}`){
     display__img.innerHTML = `<img src='${e.target.src}'/img>`
     display__title.innerHTML = `${project.title}  <a href="${project.github}" target="__blank"><img class='icon__git' src="./images/GitHub-Mark-32px.png"/></a>`;
     display__desc.innerHTML = `${project.description}`;
    }

```
I added also a function that adds a project.title class to slide's classList :)